# Delphi with command only changing properties of last object

Tags: delphi, with-statement

Delphi *with* command not working correctly?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  With Label1, Label2 do
  begin
    caption := 'Hello'
  end;
end;
```

I tried to use this code above in a super simple program but the button only changes the caption property of the Label2, NOT label1. When code looks like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  With Label1 do
  begin
    caption := 'Hello'
  end;
end;
```

It correctly changes the properties of Label1. How do I need to change the code in order for it to change the properties of both objects?

Comment: There's a really easy fix for this, which is: When you realize your fingers have typed `with`, quickly hit backspace 4 times and start over.

Comment: `with` is a common source of programming errors.

Comment: Which documentation did you read that suggested a single assignment statement would modify properties of multiple objects? We must find out so that we are sure never to recommend that source to anyone else.

Comment: Don't be fooled to think that `with` provides an "elegant" programming style. On the contrary, it provides nightmares you don't want to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Delphi documentation:

When multiple objects or records appear after with, the entire statement is treated like a series of nested with statements. Thus

```
 with obj1, obj2, ..., objn do statement
```

is equivalent to

```
 with obj1 do
   with obj2 do
     ...
     with objn do
       // statement
```

In this case, each variable reference or method name in statement is interpreted, if possible, as a member of objn; otherwise it is interpreted, if possible, as a member of objn1; and so forth. The same rule applies to interpreting the objs themselves, so that, for instance, if objn is a member of both obj1 and obj2, it is interpreted as obj2.objn.

As you've discovered, this is just one place where **with** doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Straightforward:

```
Label1.Caption := 'Hello';
Label2.Caption := 'Hello';
```

Just some advise: Don't use `with`!

In your first code, the `with` for *Label2* catches the scope and hides the *Caption* property of *Label1*. In general, if you want two assignments you have to write two assignments. You might use a loop depending on the situation, but this example is easiest done as shown above.

If you have a recent Delphi version you can write something like this:

```
var
  lbl: TLabel;
begin
  for lbl in TArray<TLabel>.Create(Label1, Label2) do
    lbl.Caption := 'Hello';
end;
```

IMHO, this is even worse - at least for this case.